# How do I split a very long %w line in ruby

Tags: ruby

I have a very long string array that I wrote using %w

```
names = %w(FOO BAR BAZZ HELLO WORLD.....)
```

It is around 500+ char long line.
I want to split(a.k.a read as WRAP) for readability.

What is a recommended way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change lines at certain points.

```
names = %w(
  FOO BAR BAZZ HELLO WORLD
  FOO BAR BAZZ HELLO WORLD
  FOO BAR BAZZ HELLO WORLD
  FOO BAR BAZZ HELLO WORLD
  FOO BAR BAZZ HELLO WORLD
  ...
)
```